Necessary algorithms and their structures to ensure minimum performance of small satellites based on PLD/FPGA
Let's consider small satellites whose on-board computer core is PLD/FPGA. From their generalized system architecture (taken, for example, from A Generic Simulink Model Template
for Simulation of Small Satellites) it is clear that small satellites include at least 5 subsystems: telemetry (communication), power, attitude control, payload and the on-board computer itself with PLD/FPGA.

An on-board computer with PLD/FPGA controls other subsystems of the small satellite and ensures their interactions.
Let's look at the rest:

Telemetry (communication) - ensures communication between the spacecraft and ground stations and transmission of data from target systems.
Power - converts solar energy into electrical energy and stores it in batteries to power all spacecraft systems.
Attitude control - ensures the orientation of the spacecraft in space and stabilization of its position relative to the center of mass.
Payload - helps accomplish mission objectives.

The problem is that these are too general formulations.
Function 3 can be specified, for example, synthesized and controlled using a PID controller, then a block diagram and solution algorithm can be constructed. With power, everything is also more or less clear, for example, maximize the power of the solar panel using the MPPT algorithm. With functions 1 and 4 everything is much more complicated. Firstly, the payload is connected to the PLD/FPGA through various interfaces, and it is not clear what information is retrieved, in what form the data is transmitted, how it is structured, and how the FPGA interacts with it. Secondly, in what form are signals received and transmitted, what kind of processing they undergo, through what channels.
In other words, there are a lot of nuances associated with interfaces, their configuration, transmission, reception, processing and storage of information, etc. In other words, there are a lot of nuances associated with interfaces, their configuration, transmission, reception, processing and storage of information, etc.
Can anyone help me with this and briefly tell me what algorithms and structures should be embedded in the PLD/FPGA to ensure minimum performance of the small satellites?
Just an example of a tutorial project:
Let's assume that the goals and objectives of the mission, scientific instruments (camera, spectrograph) and other equipment (motors, sensors, etc.) have been determined. Let us further assume that two versions of an on-board computer are being developed, one of which is based on an FPGA. We need to program the FPGA based on the following:

satellite rotates in a geocentric orbit, camera is always oriented towards the Sun (except for the time when the sun is covered by the Earth)
downlink signal is bursty. Every $2$ hours it transmits a signal in the form $1111110$ to the ground (here the first bit $1$ is the readiness of transmission, $11111$ is confirmation of the operability of all subsystems, bits $0$ is the signal of the end of transmission). Pulse duration $1 µs$.
Once every $6$ hours, a photograph of the sun from the camera and the measured spectrum are photographed/measured and transmitted to the ground. Priority: the photo is transmitted first, then the spectrum. The photo is compressed and stored in flash memory. I can’t say anything about the spectrometer signal, because I don't know in what form it is usually measured.
If the battery charge drops below $30$%, and the sun is in sight, then you need to switch to charging mode (constantly orient the solar panels towards the sun).
The error in pointing the camera at the sun is no more than $10^{\circ}$, the solar panel is no more than $5^{\circ}$.


I don't know if there's a way to save the questions here, but I do want to say the example mission almost seems like a trick question you'd ask during an interview to see which engineers will say "why don't you just point the camera along the solar panel axis and reduce your pointing constraints from two to one"

@ErinAnne There is no trick to the question. The main goal is to understand how similar tasks can be implemented on FPGAs.

You don't start from a PLD/FPGA. You first figure out specific mission requirements, and then architect a solution that includes a variety of technologies chosen for their specific applicability to the problem. Those technologies may include PLDs and FPGAs, but they may not. "God is in the details".
For communication, is the nature of your downlink continuous or bursty? Do you need to prioritize data sources? How many bits do you need? What error rate is acceptible? Many other questions...
Attitude control is complicated, not a mere PID loop. At least six degrees of mechanical freedom coupled in nonlinear ways with feedback from complicated, imperfectly reliable sensors and control via complicated actuators. Star trackers don't see through bright light, and when a star tracker sees a star, which star is it (maybe it's a lens flare)? A narrow field Sun sensor will have trouble acquiring, while a wide field Sun sensor in LEO will be influenced by bright reflections from clouds. Neither will work in eclipse. Wheel bearings stick and chatter, magnetometers are affected by other electrical machinery. Detumbling is different from 3-axis pointing, and you usually want a "safe mode" that can charge the batteries and communicate but may not be useful for anything else.

Look at the edit of my question. I've edited it to reflect your current answer. The only thing he didn’t indicate was the required bit capacity of the ADC. You are right, there are a great many nuances. But first I need to learn how to do basic things, ensuring minimal performance, improving the program in the future (let's imagine that all the sensors are ideal, and the data is transmitted without errors).

@dtn You haven't motivated the selection of the PLD/FPGA as a technology. For most of that stuff we use processors.

I was just inspired by the "flying laptop"
